# Search a listbox, results will not highlight when searching results found

Tags: vb.net

I have run into a problem that I don't understand and frustration is blocking my though process.

I have a text file that is read and loaded into a listbox. I have a search that worked on a previous attempt but the functionality wasn't quite right, I had the results in a separate list box but could not figure out the removal process as it wouldn't update the original list box after the removal. So I opted to keep things simple or so I thought and just wanted to use one list box.

The textchanged txtSearch code is below and it does not highlight the individual search item. I tried lstMain.SelectedItem = True, lstMain.SelectedItem = item I'm guessing that this is due to the fact that the lstMain.SelectedItem needs an Integer value and I'm using string to choose a certain amount of data on each line within the text file, similar to columns and rows.

```
For Each item As String In lstMain.SelectedItems
    If item.ToUpper.Substring(0, 24).Contains(strSearchField.ToUpper) Then
        lstMain.SelectedItem
            End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic would only work if the last item was the match.

```
For Each item As String In lstMain.SelectedItems
  If item.ToUpper.Substring(0, 24).Contains(strSearchField.ToUpper) Then
    lstMain.SelectedItem = item
    Exit For 'so the found item stays selected
  End If
Next
```

or

```
For i As Integer = 0 To lstMain.Items.Count - 1
  If lstMain.Items(i).ToUpper.Substring(0, 24).Contains(strSearchField.ToUpper) Then
    lstMain.SelectedIndex = i
    Exit For 'so the found item stays selected
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Having only the last item selected was not what I was intending. I had thought that the if then statement would have gone through lstMain.Items and if it matched the strSearchField it would have then highlighted each match with lstMain.SelectedItem. The Exit for did remove the original error I was having.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to highlight the searched word in a `listbox`, isn't it? if so the following code will help you:

```
 Dim searchWord As String = "apple"
 If ListBox1.Items.Contains(searchWord) Then
    ListBox1.SelectedItem = searchWord
 End If
```

Comment: I had tried that but when I get more specific by using If ListBox1.Substring(10, 20).Items, vb.net says that substring is not a member of system.windows.forms.listbox. The reasoning behind this is to eliminate case sensitive searches even though the items listed in the listbox do have upper and lower case charachters.